# PG_Fetch_Objects returns only one row from recursive query

Tags: php, postgresql, recursion, php-5.6, postgresql-10

I am really desperate on this issue and I can't find any helpful reference via google although this is suppost to be easy to solve. At least I thought so.

For performance reasons I replaced a function to use Postgres' recursive WITH queries. My issue:
pg_fetch_object returns only one single row, although pg_num_rows returns the correct amount of rows (104). The query itself is okay, I get clean results with other query tools.

I hope someone can help me, I need to use pg_fetch_object to collect ALL rows of a query result and not just the first row.
Please I have no idea what I have done wrong. This is the code:

```
public function getSelfAndAncestorsRecursive($id) {
    $animal = array();
    if ($id != "") {

//Here comes the query string
$query = "WITH RECURSIVE Ancestors AS
(SELECT 
animals.id, animals.name, animals.\"animalID\",
animals.sex, animals.\"birthDate\", animals.alive, animals.deleted, cages.\"cageName\",
animals.dummy_strain_info AS strain, animals.dummy_line_info AS line, animals.dummy_gen_info AS gene,
animals.generation, animals.dummy_backcross_info,
animals.\"parentMale\" AS sire, animals.\"parentFemale\" AS dam
FROM animals
LEFT OUTER JOIN cages ON \"homeCage\" = cages.id
WHERE animals.id = ".$id
."UNION ALL
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.\"animalID\", 
a.sex, a.\"birthDate\", a.alive, a.deleted, c.\"cageName\", 
a.dummy_strain_info AS Astrain, a.dummy_line_info AS Aline, a.dummy_gen_info AS Agene,
a.generation, a.dummy_backcross_info,
a.\"parentMale\" AS Asire, a.\"parentFemale\" AS Adam
FROM animals a
LEFT OUTER JOIN cages c ON a.\"homeCage\" = c.id
INNER JOIN Ancestors n ON a.id = n.sire::int8 OR a.id = n.dam::int8
)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Ancestors
ORDER BY id DESC;";


//Parse Query and fetch result
  $res = pg_query($query);
  while ($row = pg_fetch_object($res) {

      //Set array values
      $animal["id"] = $row->id;
      $animal["name"] = $row->name;
      $animal["animal_id"] = $row->animalID;
      $animal["birth_date"] = $row->birthDate;
      $animal["sex"] = $row->sex;
      $animal["alive"] = $row->alive;
      $animal["deleted"] = $row->deleted;
      $animal["cage"] = $row->cageName;
          $animal["strain"] = $row->strain;
          $animal["line"] = $row->line;
          $animal["gene"] = $row->gene;
          $animal["generation"] = $row->generation;
          $animal["backcross"] = $row->dummy_backcross_info;
          $animal["sire"] = $row->sire;
          $animal["dam"] = $row->dam;      
    }

    }
    return $animal;
  }
```

Comment: as of PHP 7.1 `pg_fetch_all()` should work, otherwise don't overwrite your return variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah thanks nice but that is not actually what I needed to know.
When using pg_fetch_all, I get a multidimensional index-based array that I cannot use.

To be honest, I have a hard time transposing 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 12345...
to
Array ( [id] => 380619...

but I will keep trying by my self